# I cannot seem to get my config.yml file too work on circleci

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, cypress, circleci, cd

I'm new to circleci and i'm trying to schedule a run of a cypress test once every 24 hours, I have this config.yml file in my github repo which should work (i think) but i'm getting "config.yml is not valid" but i'm not sure where i should start debugging:

```html
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
'on':
  schedule:
    - cron: 0 1-23 * * *
    - cron: 0 0 * * *
workflows:
  version: 2
  release: null
jobs: null
test_schedule:
  name: Test schedule
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Skip this step every 24 hours
      if: github.event_name == 'schedule' && github.event.schedule != '0 0 * * *'
      run: echo "This step will be skipped every 24 hours"
    - test: null
  triggers:
    - schedule:
        cron: 0 0 * * *
```

Any pointers where i'm going wrong? Thanks,

Error message on CircleCI shows:

Value does not match schema: {:workflows {:release {:jobs (not (map? nil))}}}

But from what I can see it's the correct order?

Comment: I get a build error on circleci stating the file is not valid, however no validation errors are returned when I use an online validator.

Comment: Can you format your yml file and add it again? And also add the error into your question.

Comment: So sorry @AlapanDas - I was quick too upload there and didn't realize it hadn't formatted correctly, it should be fine now.